# Integration over Sphere

Tags: integration, proof-verification, spheres

I have a question to a pretty basic integration problem. I was pretty sure about my solution but my tutor had a different one such that I am confused now. The integral is the following:

$$\int_{S_r(0)} z^2 d S_r(0)$$

Using the standard parameterization, I obtain:

$$d S = r^2 \sin(\theta) d \theta d \phi$$

$$\int_{S_r(0)} z^2 d S_r(0) = \int_{0}^{2 \pi}  \int_{0}^{\pi}  r^2 \cos^2(\theta)  r^2 \sin(\theta) d \theta d \phi = \dots = \frac{4 r^4\pi}{3}$$

I would be very glad if someone could verify or falsify the result!

Thanks much in advance

Andreas

Comment: Can you encase your tex syntax in dollar and double dollar cases?

Answer (score 0):

$I=r^4\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\phi .\left(-\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi}cos^2\theta 
 \ d(cos\theta)\right)$

$I=\dfrac{1}{3}r^4\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\phi .\left[cos^3\theta\right]_{\pi}^{0}$

$I=\dfrac{2}{3}r^4\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\phi $

$I=\left(\dfrac{2}{3}r^4.2\pi\right)=\dfrac{4\pi}{3}r^4 $

Comment: Thank you!.. As I stated, that’s exactly my result as well. Does it make a difference when I write $\int_{S_r(0)} z^2 dvol_{S_r(0)}$ ?